# how to reauthenticate user with firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I'm new to firebase.
In my nuxt js project with multiple pages, firestore rule is set to read or write once request.auth != null.

so if when refresh in a page, auth will be gone and it display error 'permission-denied' in terminal.

i tried Authentication State Persistence LOCAL but it doesn't work.
What is the purpose of using these auth persistence mode ?

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
.then(function() {
return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth session is **automatically persistent on the frontend** of your app, however Nuxt.js contains frontend and backend part. If you are storing user data somewhere on the frontend, you probably need to wait until the user data become accessible.

Example of the **listener**:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
          if (user) {
            console.log('User is logged: ', user);
          }
        });
```

However this will make user accessible only on the frontend, if you want to preload data **on the backend you would need to store id and refresh token in the cookies** **or** use [Nuxt Firebase](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/tutorials/ssr/) module which should handle **service worker** for you.

**So, in your case it looks like you are trying to read the data before your user data become accessible (this can be caused by trying to fetch data on the backend).**